# Почему вылетает apache?

Tags: apache, xampp

Вот логи:

```
 [Fri Nov 29 10:20:50.759781 2013] [core:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
    [Fri Nov 29 10:20:51.615183 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9964
    [Fri Nov 29 10:20:56.320404 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 9964:tid 420] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Fri Nov 29 10:20:57.158656 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9964:tid 420] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
    [Fri Nov 29 10:50:35.628034 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
    [Fri Nov 29 10:50:38.277036 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Fri Nov 29 10:50:40.297431 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Fri Nov 29 10:50:40.297431 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
    [Fri Nov 29 10:50:40.297431 2013] [core:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
    [Fri Nov 29 10:50:40.327461 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4520
    [Fri Nov 29 10:50:44.303475 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4520:tid 416] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Fri Nov 29 10:50:45.106556 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4520:tid 416] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
    zend_mm_heap corrupted
    [Fri Nov 29 10:58:59.375625 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 1 -- Restarting.
    [Fri Nov 29 10:59:00.948677 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Fri Nov 29 10:59:04.836473 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Fri Nov 29 10:59:04.836473 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
    [Fri Nov 29 10:59:04.836473 2013] [core:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
    [Fri Nov 29 10:59:04.839477 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 420] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2424
    [Fri Nov 29 10:59:08.609893 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 2424:tid 416] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
    [Fri Nov 29 10:59:10.646898 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2424:tid 416] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 1):

Установи [Win32 OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)